# Saving a file uses unexplainably large amounts of storage

Tags: android

In my application the user can choose a file using the chooser Intent, which will then be "imported" into the application and saved in internal storage for security reasons. This all worked fine and still does on some devices, but for example on the Google Pixel on Android 7.1.1 it only functions normally for the first 4-6 files and afterwards it acts very odd.
The performance was going down drastically so I checked my storage usage and found that it was continuously growing, although the file I was supposed to be saving was less than 1mb large. Importing a file would cause the amount of storage taken by my app to rise past 500mb and upward. I can't seem to find the cause for this.

The method I am using to save the files which is called in an async background task:

```
BufferedInputStream bis = null;
BufferedOutputStream bos = null;
OutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
int size = 0;
InputStream fis = getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);
try{
     bis = new BufferedInputStream(fis);
     bos = new BufferedOutputStream(fos);
     byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
     int len = 1024;
     while((len = bis.read(buf,0,len)) != -1){
         bos.write(buf,0,len);
         size = size+1024;
         Log.v("Bytes written",""+size);
     }
}catch (IOException e){
     e.printStackTrace();
}finally {
     try{
         if(bis != null) bis.close();
         if(bos != null) bos.close();
         if(fis != null) fis.close();
         if(fos != null) fos.close();
     }catch(IOException e){
          e.printStackTrace();
     }
}

return Uri.fromFile(file);
```

The Uri which this function returns is then saved in an SQLite Database to be used later.

I appreciate all kinds of tips as to where this memory usage could be coming from.

Btw, this did not result from an update on the phone nor from any changes in my code, as it was working the last time I tested it and I haven't changed anything since.

Comment: Maybe the problem is somewhere else, e.g. you trigger this operation multiple times?

Comment: Not a solution but a general suggestion for file/network I/O - it's a shame to implement it yourself, potentially missing some spots (e.g `fos` can stay open, read() doesn't guarantee to fill the buffer), when you have libraries such as Okio at your disposal. Copying a file in 3 lines: https://twitter.com/jessewilson/status/529497763625455616?

Comment: @AndrzejZabost I've already tried checking this using breakpoints but couldn't find any multiple calls. The asyncTask which saves the file is called from onActivityResult.

Comment: `size = size+1024;` That should be   size = size+len;

Comment: @greenapps That makes more sense, I'll change it. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had an additional method which would append an index to a file added multiple times eg. "file.pdf", "file1.pdf","file2.pdf". This method wasn't correct, leading to an endless loop of creating a new file and appending an index. I managed to fix the problem by changing this method to avoid looping.

In retrospect I should have included that in my question.

Answer (score 0):

I see a couple of things to correct:

1) The signature of the write method doesn't seem correct, if you write from a buffer you should use `write(buff, offset, length)`.

2) You read into the buffer once, so it should be enugh to write out the buffer once too.

3) If you need to read the the buffer more than once, and write out the values more than once, use a `while`, not a `do while`. You have no garantee that the read operation was succesfull.

[Ref to write method in Android Developer](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/BufferedOutputStream.html#write(byte[],%20int,%20int))

Comment: I've changed my code following your suggestions (Which make sense, I hadn't thought about it that much) but it still has the same problem.

Comment: The first time you are reading twice. The first read is getting lost.

Comment: Also check the read signature, it is missing the offset and legth. https://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/BufferedInputStream.html#read(byte[],%20int,%20int)

Comment: The first read was a typo in the question, I had removed it in my code. I've adjusted the code again, but still see no difference. Thanks a lot for your tips though.

Comment: Just in case, before closing the file, flush the output.